# How to use a different compiler with CMake (IAR)?

Tags: cmake

I've noticed that CMake is installed with numerous modules such as the IAR compiler:

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake

In a previous question I asked how to load this particular module. The answer was just to add:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER iccarm.exe)
```

on my `CMakeLists.txt`.

Unfortunately I noticed, this is not enough because the `IAR.cmake` is never really used. With the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER iccarm.exe)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

list(APPEND src src/main.c)

project("foo" C)

add_executable(foo ${src})

message(STATUS "IARARM_CMAKE_LOADED=${_IARARM_CMAKE_LOADED}")
message(STATUS "IAR CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT=${CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT}")
```

I get this output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is IAR
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IAR Systems/Embedded Workbench 8.0/arm/bin/iccarm.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- IARARM_CMAKE_LOADED=
-- IAR CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT=<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <SOURCE> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT>
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Ycr/Home/sandbox/cmake
```

Where `IARARM_CMAKE_LOADED` isn't defined and `CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT` doesn't have the `--silent` option defined [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake)

How can I tell CMake to use the IAR Module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I slowly begin to realize the issues.

- you shall not define the compiler in the `CMakeLists.txt` file. you add them as argument on the commandline like `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=iccarm.exe ...`
  Compiler detection usually happens before your `CMakeLists.txt` file gets touched
- Are you sure you are using the nightly build, because the file you linked is not in the relased builds but will be included in CMake 3.10

Add the versions and the commandline used to invoke CMake next time. Also you have some options like `--trace-expand` that should give you an idea what (does not) happens.

Comment: Well, I am starting to understand too. The modification with the `--silent` was added 3 months ago so it is a pretty recent change and my `CMake` for windows was 3.9.1, not 3.9.2. As I was looking at the sources directly from GitHub (and from CMake on my Cygwin installation that was 3.9.2), I got confused.

Comment: `--trace-expand` greatly helped me!

Comment: I still got confused though. The [d8e6cd9ed](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/d8e6cd9ed8bfee9073cff26cb654bc01e653b0b9) that you made seems not to be part of **v3.9.2**, but your change is right after **v3.9.0-rc4**. It is like a dead end. How is it organized, the Git repository is full of noisy `Merge branch 'release-3.9'` everywhere.